# JoomShopping. How to show other products on product page?

Tags: joomla

Well. I hate JoomShopping.
In template of product page i do smth like that:

```
$category_id = $this->category_id;
$category = JSFactory::getTable('category', 'jshop');
$category->load($category_id);
$products = $category->getProducts();
```

I got an array of products with everything I need. Except Links.
Show me another way (for examle, explain how it works on category page.

Answer (score 1):

If you need objects with links, so try:

```
$category_id = $this->category_id;
$category = JSFactory::getTable('category', 'jshop');
$category->load($category_id);
$products = $category->getProducts();
addLinkToProducts($products, $categorys->$category_id);

var_dump($products);
```